# skiasharp- image resize with white background SKImageInfo instead of black background c#

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I am trying to resize an image with the following code:

```
protected virtual byte[] ImageResize(SKBitmap image, SKEncodedImageFormat format, int targetSize)
        {            
            if (image == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Image is null");

            float width, height;
            if (image.Height > image.Width)
            {
                // portrait
                width = image.Width * (targetSize / (float)image.Height);
                height = targetSize;
            }
            else
            {
                // landscape or square
                width = targetSize;
                height = image.Height * (targetSize / (float)image.Width);
            }

            if ((int)width == 0 || (int)height == 0)
            {
                width = image.Width;
                height = image.Height;
            }
            try
            {
                using var resizedBitmap = image.Resize(new SKImageInfo((int)width, (int)height), SKFilterQuality.Medium);
                
                using var cropImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                

                //In order to exclude saving pictures in low quality at the time of installation, we will set the value of this parameter to 80 (as by default)
                return cropImage.Encode(format, _mediaSettings.DefaultImageQuality > 0 ? _mediaSettings.DefaultImageQuality : 80).ToArray();
            }
            catch
            {
                return image.Bytes;
            }

        }
```

My image is getting resized with black background, but I want to set white or transparent background instead of black.